My Domain gets all the time blocked by spamhaus
I am really desperate.
My domain rump-pump.de is constantly being blocked by Spamhaus.
My server provider, Ultahost, doesn't have a proper answer and has been trying to fix it for 3 weeks without success.
Since we are an online store, it is really bad that our emails are not working because we can't send emails to our customers regarding payments and order confirmations.
Does anyone have experience with how I can fix this as soon as possible?
We have a VPS by Ultahost.

Create a free google account for now

I don't know ultrahost specifically, but if you are purchasing just a VPS from them and not paying $$$ for support, it would be unreasonable to expect support for email problems related to your VPS from them.    Generally if you are purchasing just a VPS without a support contract it would be unreasonable to expect them to fix email problems related to your VPS setup as its quite specialist.

There are a few parts to this.   Start off by looking at https://check.spamhaus.org/listed/?searchterm=rump-pump.de - which basically says that you have not been practicing email best practices, and your domain is associated with spam.   It also recommends best practices for you to follow and offers you the chance to remove the domain.
There are also weird things going on with your domain.  When I do a DNS lookup for your MX record the domain associated with that is cp.ultrahost.com - however cp.ultrahost.com does not exist.  This could set alarm bells ringing off the charts as there are MAJOR setup issues.
On a hunch, I then checked if rump-pump.de is responding on port 25.  It is.  This likely means that correct email routing is failing and a direct connection is being used as a fallback.  This is about as far from a best practice as you can get.   It also means you are relying on your own (from reverse DNS I guess plex) server to act as your mail server - and you don't have the skills to maintain it (don't take that the wrong way - it is hard and time consuming to do this properly).
A significant part of the solution is to stop trying to host your own emails on your VPS and move to a provider who specialises in it  Most people use GMAIL (you will need a paid account, not a free one), or a Microsoft Outlook account.
Another thing you want to do - Your website appears to be using Wordpress as the backend.  Seriously consider getting PostSMTP or similar and relay your emails through your Outlook or Gmail setup - or switch to relaying your email through a provider that specializes in bulk email - there are a handful listed in https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-smtp/ - and I can also add smtp2go to that list (which is free for small volumes).
Once you have got this under control, restrict your SPF record so that it is default fail, add DKIM - which means if someone is sending spam and pretending to be you they will fail, and add DMARC to tie this together.   Most good mass mail providers will provide settings/advice on this, but you may want to get a specialist in to help.
Once you have started doing mail properly, request to be removed from the Spamhaus blocklist.
(Note that it is unlikely your email is being blocked by reputable provders solely because you are in Spamhaus - it is generally one of many signals used to assess your credibility.  Your email credibility is low because its set up incorrectly and on the cheap)

Hi Davidgo,
thank you for your solution.
We have moved our mail to Google but it still dont work. We are still blocked by spamhaus. I dont know what to do anymore..
